# How do I shrink the space in between the icons the tray icon panel on my taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, task-manager, notification-area

How do I shrink the space in between each icon on the taskbar's hidden tray icon panel when clicking the angle button?
Currently it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look something like this (visualization done in Aseprite):

[image]

Sure, it may be a bit hard to click on the icons, but I'll get used to it. If I can, am I able to adjust the spacing between the icons (using the registry editor or third party program) to become more compact AND easily clickable?

Comment: The limit of what you can natively do is use small task bar icons (task bar properties). Otherwise you need some registry hack.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to modify this, Registry or otherwise, as it's controlled by the [Windows Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell). Most parts pf the Windows Shell that can be customized using Stardock's [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds) in Windows 10 and under, but the tray icon spacing in general has never been customizable at all AFAIK _(WindowBlinds allows customization of most parts of the Windows Shell)_

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *rege*.
- Select *Regedit* and open it.
- [Navigate](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/desktop-icon-spacing/89acd4b9-7fec-47be-939b-35b26b807d5f) to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`.
- Double-click the value *IconSpacing*. Change it to reduce [*horizontal* spacing](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16941-change-desktop-icon-spacing-windows-10-a.html). Default is -1125, and the minimum is -480 (think "minimum" in *absolute* value... you'll have to ask MS the logic for this), and "max", -2730.
- Double-click the value *IconVerticalSpacing*. Change it to [reduce *vertical* spacing](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16941-change-desktop-icon-spacing-windows-10-a.html). Default and range is as above.

  If those two don't yet exist, right-click the right pane and add *New > REG_SZ* with each of the above values. Again, why REG_SZ for a numeric field, ask MS.
- Now close all your work, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> and  select *Switch user*. The values *should* take effect after logging in again.

*Caveat:* Microsoft may have taken away the effect of those Registry values in some Windows 10 and 11 builds.

- Also, while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, click on the Desktop and rotate the mouse wheel to change icon font and size -- that *still* works.

Comment: Doesn't this also reduce the icon spacing on the desktop and in explorer windows? (I haven't tried it and don't want to if it does).